# How to forward port through VPN on Linux

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, openvpn

I'm setting up a small CTF (hacker competition) and have a machine that hosts VMs. One of these VMs will be the target.

The host machine cannot be reached through the internet, so I have set up a Digital Ocean machine as an OpenVPN server and the VM host as a client. The following diagram shows the setup:
[image: Network setup]

My OpenVPN configuration allows for traffic between clients and a route to the VM network (virtnet) has been pushed. This part works, and the Jump host can reach the 192.168.160.12 machine.

On the Jump host I have added the following firewall rules:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -d 192.168.160.12 -p tcp --dport 11000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 11000 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.160.12:11000
```

On the VMHost machine I did this:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -o tun1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -i tun1 -j ACCEPT
```

I believe this should be enough to route traffic from the internet through to the 192.168.160.12 VM, however it is not.

It reaches the VMHost machine but is not forwarded to the VM. When doing a netcat from the Jump host (`nc 192.168.160.12 11000`) everything works fine. The VM is reached and it responds, but when I do the same from across the internet (`nc 178.62.XXX.YYY 11000` from the Me machine) the traffic reaches the Jump host, is forwarded to the VMHost, reaches the VMHost on the tun1 interface, but is not forwarded onto the virbr0 interface as it is when the Jump host was the originator.

Why this difference?

Comment: I think it is not enough information for an answer. Are any other `iptables` rules defined on **Jump** and **VMHost** and is IP forwarding enabled? I think it would be required to enable SNAT on **Jump**. Then the routing tables on both hosts are important. And I guess that **VMHost** is the default gateway of **CTF**? **Jump** should have a route to `192.168.160.0/24` or whatever the network address is. The difference in your 2 attempts is the source IP address, which in the first attempt is `10.20.0.1` and in the second the IP address of **Me**. `10.20.0.1` should be gateway of **VMHost**.

Comment: That last part was it. The default route on VMHost was not tun1 but eth0, so  Reverse Path Filtering simply dropped the packets that would not be able to find their way back. The solution was to add 'redirect-gateway autolocal' to the OpenVPN config file on VMHost.

Comment: Nice. Do you have any SNAT rules on **Jump**? I was not sure if this is required or happens automatically for the forwarded connection. But I would be interested to know.

Comment: Yes, I had to add SNAT on Jump. It didn't work until I added it, so apparently it does not happen automatically.